# What is the PAGER used by info pages?

Tags: emacs, info, pager

When typing the command `info` you get a long output with header as:

```
File: dir,      Node: Top       This is the top of the INFO tree

  This (the Directory node) gives a menu of major topics.
  Typing "q" exits, "?" lists all Info commands, "d" returns here,
  "h" gives a primer for first-timers,
  "mEmacs<Return>" visits the Emacs manual, etc.

  In Emacs, you can click mouse button 2 on a menu item or cross reference
  to select it.
```

So, from the heading I assume that using emacs as the default PAGER but when running the command

```
emacs
```

output shows:

```
The program 'emacs' can be found in the following packages:
 * emacs23
 * emacs23-nox
 * e3
 * emacs23-lucid
 * jove
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Then what is the pager of `info` pages? Is there is some bundled `emacs` or some like?!

Comment: Have a look at this doc [Emacs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmacsHowto) whether this assist you with some idea.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [online info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/info.html)

> There are two ways to use Info: from within Emacs or as a stand-alone reader that you can invoke from a shell using the command info.

I guess `info` has no external pager like *man* but *info* IS the pager.

Comment: It looks like you're quoting something. What?

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/info` (from package `info`) is a standalone info page viewer. It's not related to Emacs.

See `info info` for more about `info`.

The text you see if you start `infO` without an argument isn't created by `info` but the default info node (usually `/usr/share/info/dir`)

Comment: I think info still use emacs. I came with http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsManual

Comment: @Maythux you can use Emacs, but those who don't want to can use info. Emacs isn't installed by default. Info is.

Comment: @muru please look at the links in my answer, that make me confused, even I'm sure that `info` is the page viewer but as I understand from links it used `emacs` or to be more precise many characteristics of it.

Comment: @muru, how to use emacs to view info pages?

Comment: What's to be confused about? `info` is for those users who don't want to use Emacs. It's possible it borrows commands from Emacs, after all they are both GNU programs.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/:

> Texinfo is the official documentation format of the GNU project. It
>   was invented by Richard Stallman and Bob Chassell many years ago,
>   loosely based on Brian Reid's Scribe and other formatting languages of
>   the time. It is used by many non-GNU projects as well.
>        Texinfo uses a single source file to produce output in a number of formats, both online and printed (dvi, html, info, pdf, xml, etc.).
>   This means that instead of writing different documents for online
>   information and another for a printed manual, you need write only one
>   document. And when the work is revised, you need revise only that one
>   document. **The Texinfo system is well-integrated with GNU Emacs.**

To learn how to use texinfo read http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Texinfo

Reading some [emacs WIKI](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoMode):

> This page is about Info mode (‘C-h i’), a major mode for reading
>   hypertext manuals. In particular, the EmacsManual is available in
>   Emacs as an Info manual, providing SelfDocumentation.

Quoted from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsManual:

> Emacs comes with a comprehensive manual. Access it through Info,
>   either with the info command in a shell window under GNU and Unix
>   operating systems, or in Emacs, by typing ‘M-x info RET’ (that’s Meta-
>   or ESC x, the word “info”, followed by the return key), or by typing
>   ‘C-h i’ (that’s Control-h followed by i). Starting with Emacs 22, you
>   can also read the manual with ‘C-h r’.

As a conclusion info pages use `Textinfo` documentation format but as said in the GNU [Textinfo wiki](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/:) **The Texinfo system is well-integrated with GNU Emacs**.